# Passing an array to another method in an applet

Tags: java, methods, applet

So I am writing a program that randomly picks 10 cards in a deck and displays them. However, I can't figure out how to pass the array with I use to store the random cards to the method in which I print out the cards. This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class unit12Assignment extends Applet
{
    Image card1 ... card52;

public void init()
{
    card1 = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "c1.gif" );
        ...
    card52 = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "sk.gif" );
}

public void getCards(String[] cardSelection)
{
    String cardNumber; 
    double cardRandom;
    int cardRandomNumber;
    Random ran = new Random();
            cardSelection = new String[10]

    for (int number = 0; number <=  9; )
    {
        cardRandom = ran.nextInt(52) + 1;
        cardRandomNumber = (int) Math.round( cardRandom );

        if ( cardRandomNumber > 0 && cardRandomNumber <= 52 )
        { 
            cardNumber =  "card" + cardRandomNumber;
            number++;
        }
    }   
}

    // i wanna pass it to this method
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    setBackground( Color.green );
    g.drawImage( cardSelection[0], 10, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( cardSelection[1], 90, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( cardSelection[2], 170, 10, this);
    g.drawImage( cardSelection[3], 250, 10, this);
}
```

}

Its seems like a simple problem but I completely forgot how to do it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Make cardSelection as a global variable so it will be accessible for all methods

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `paint` method accept a `String[]`.  Then you can pass in your array when you call `paint`.

For example:

```
public void main(String[] args) {
  String[] myArray = makeArray();
  printArray(myArray);
}   

public String[] makeArray() {
  return new String[] {"element0", "element1", "element2"};
}   

public void printArray(String[] array) {
  for (String element : array) {
    System.out.println(element);
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `String[] cardSelection;` as an instance variable (next to the class declaration).

Then, in the getCards() method instantiate the array:

```
cardSelection = new String[10];
```

Comment: Do you mean declare `cardSelection` as a class-level field?

Comment: Did that but the paint method still can't find it

Comment: The paint method cannot find it at the beginning as it may be called before getCards(). So you have to check if not null before using it in the paint method. Once getCards() instantiates it, it will become available to paint.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the getCards() method starts before the paint() method. I updated the question with the changes I've made. Would you mind taking a look at it? Thanks

Comment: Your changes are wrong. Just place the String[] cardSelection next to the Image card1 ... card52; (whatever this means, because this doesn't look like Java)